# Hamburger menu not functioning

Tags: javascript, html, css, hamburger-menu

I've gotten sort of close with this hamburger menu but it's still not functioning. Any help would be great. (I'm sure it's obvious but forest for the trees and all that.) To a newb, it seems like my js isn't functioning/triggering/whatever the correct word is. Perhaps I linked it wrong?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Bad Doc</title>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script> 
      $('.menu-btn').click(function(){
        $('.responsive-menu').toggleClass('expand')
      })
    </script>
    <style>

      .clearfix:after {
        content: "";
        display: table;
        clear: both;
      }


      .body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      a:hover { 
        background-color: #D3D3D3;
      }

      a:link {
        text-decoration: none;
      }

      p {
        font-family: "Garamond", Times, serif;
      }

      .wrapper {
        border: 1px solid blue;
        padding: 1px;
        background-color: gray;
      }

      .main-nav {
        border: 1px solid blue; 
        float: left;
        margin: 0 5px 0 0;
      }

      .content {
        border: 1px solid blue; 
        overflow: auto;

      }

      h1 {
        font-size: 72px;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0 0 20px 0;
        font-family: "Garamond", Times, serif;
      }

      ul {
        margin-right: 10px;
        padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
      }

      li {
        list-style-type:none;
        font-family: "Garamond", Times, serif;
        font-size: 14px;
      }

      .photos {
        text-align: center;
      }

      img {
        max-width: 30%;
        height: auto;
        opacity: 0.7;
        filter: alpha(opacity=70); 
      }   

      img:hover {
        opacity: 1.0;
        filter: alpha(opacity=100); 
      }

      #footer p {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 14px;
        border: 1px solid blue; 
        margin: 3px 0 0 0;
        padding: 3px;
        background-color: gray;
      }

      @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
        body {
          background-color: lightblue;
        }
        img {max-width: 70%; padding-bottom: 10px;
        }
        h1 {
          font-size: 30px;
        }
        .content {
          background-color: black;
          padding-right: 0;
          margin-left: 60px;
          margin-right: 60px;
        }

        .menu-btn div{
          float: left;
          padding-right: 8px;
          margin-top: 1em;
          line-height: 1.2;
          font-size: 18px;
          font-weight: 200;
          vertical-align: middle;
          z-index: 99;
        }
        .menu-btn span {
          display: block;
          width: 25px;
          height: 4px;
          margin-bottom: 5px;
          background: rgb(0,0,0);
          z-index: 99;
        }

        .responsive-menu{
          display: none;
          overflow: hidden;
        }

        .responsive-menu ul {
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          width: 100px;
          float: left;
        }

        .responsive-menu li {
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          list-style-type: none;
        }

        .expand {
          display: block !important; 
        }

        <!-- nav ends here-->

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>

    <!-- added clearfix here with style at top of style list-->
    <div class="wrapper clearfix">
      <h1>gage</h1>

      <!-- this is nav-->
      <div class="menu-btn" id="menu-btn">
        <div></div>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>

        <div class="main-nav responsive-menu">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- this is main body of page -->
      <div class="content"> 
        <div class="photos">
          <a href="google.html"><img src="25612060593_b222234b86_b.jpg"></a>
          <a href="google.html"><img src="25612060593_b222234b86_b.jpg"></a>
          <a href="google.html"><img src="25612060593_b222234b86_b.jpg"></a>
          <a href="google.html"><img src="25612060593_b222234b86_b.jpg"></a>
          <a href="google.html"><img src="25612060593_b222234b86_b.jpg"></a>
          <a href="google.html"><img src="25612060593_b222234b86_b.jpg"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- this is footer (inside or outside last div???) -->
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
      <p>More stuff</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add a JSFiddle or CodePen to your question, instead of just pasting the code here. See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Roy External sites likes those are a courtesy, not a requirement to post questions.

Comment: @Yoshi But people will be more motivated to look into code on codepen/JSfiddle, because they can start editing/fixing it right away.

Comment: @IdeaMan I understand that, though I think the tone of Roys comment is not appropriate (*...instead of just pasting...*).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The better option is to move your scripts to the end of the `body` tag.

If you can't, you need to wrap this code:

```
$('.menu-btn').click(function(){
  $('.responsive-menu').toggleClass('expand')
})
```

With `$(document).ready`

Like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.menu-btn').click(function() {
    $('.responsive-menu').toggleClass('expand')
  })
});
```

http://jsbin.com/gelode/edit?html,js

Comment: Or better - include all your javascript files at the end of your document. That way scripts will be loaded after the DOM.

Comment: If you place JS in <script> tag, it will be unable to operate the html code that goes after it.

Comment: @MoshFeu Edited and clarified qurstion a bit.

Comment: @IdeaMan yes, you are right. Unless you wrap this code with listener like `window.onload` or `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded"` or jQuery equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I see where I went wrong now. And thanks especially the bit about jsbin -- I didn't know about that.

Comment: ;) My pleasure.. Glad I could help. Good luck.